# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (â€‹ code getting included in script file)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written a very simple index.html file where I have included scripts and also styles

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mediaQuery.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="js/searchComponent.js"></script>
    <script src="js/service.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

searchComponent.js:

```
   function Search() {​

}
Search.prototype.fnInitialiseSearchComponent = function() {
    var header = document.createElement("div");
    header.class = 'header';
    $('body').get(0).appendChild(header);
    header.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="search" id="search-text" placeholder="search images">';
}
```

When trying to run the application the unicode is getting appended from somewhere and throwing an error

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, we can't tell where the Unicode BOM is getting inserted from if you can't...

Comment: Have you tried removing everything inside the curly braces?

Comment: You already know the cause of the problem and where it is. All you need to do is delete that character. I'm not sure exactly what you're asking here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extra character in your code. Remove it and try again. You can see this if you copy the code and past in jsfiddle

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Delete the entire Search function and retype it.

This will remove any hidden unicode character.

I hope it helps.